# Getting an all blank bar chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've run this code in both Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm and get the same blank bar chart in both.
Anyone know why this is happening and how to get the bar coloured?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
'Elements' : ['Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_3', 'Item_4', 'Item_5'],
'Count' : [300,10,90,100,15],
'Produces': [1,140,10,5, 90]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['potential'] = df['Count'] * df['Produces']


plt.figure()
plt.bar(x = df['Elements'], height = ['potential'])
plt.show()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqJgG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget `df` in-front of the `height = df['potential']`.

It should work as expected.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
'Elements' : ['Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_3', 'Item_4', 'Item_5'],
'Count' : [300,10,90,100,15],
'Produces': [1,140,10,5, 90]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['potential'] = df['Count'] * df['Produces']


plt.figure()
plt.bar(x = df['Elements'], height = df['potential'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You for got one `df`:

```
plt.bar(x = df['Elements'], height = df['potential'])
#                                    ^ this
```

Also consider

```
df.plot.bar(x='Elements', y='potential')
```